# Android systrace is not working

Tags: android, python

I am using Systrace to  analyze the performance of app.

I tried following command,

```
python systrace.py --time=10 -o mynewtrace.html sched gfx view wm
```

But getting following error,

```
E:\sdk\android-sdk\platform-tools\systrace>python systrace.py --time=10 -o mynew
trace.html sched gfx view wm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "systrace.py", line 286, in <module>
    main()
  File "systrace.py", line 60, in main
    device_sdk_version = get_device_sdk_version()
  File "systrace.py", line 44, in get_device_sdk_version
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "E:\sdk\android-sdk\platform-tools\systrace\lib\subprocess.py", line 710,
 in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "E:\sdk\android-sdk\platform-tools\systrace\lib\subprocess.py", line 958,
 in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I am using **Kitkat** on **Moto e device** with **python 2.7**.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this (or a very similar looking) problem by adding the Android SDK tools to the PATH. Be sure to include the following paths to your PATH variable:

```
/path/to/sdk/tools
/path/to/sdk/platform-tools
```

Also, there are plenty similar threads to this already on stackoverflow.

Comment: What exactly does our PATH variable say then?
Also, does executing it with "python2" make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your SDK platform-tool version, it worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Using `sudo` mode working for me.